# How to modify Vuetify default theme?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

In other words, my question is what does `<v-toolbar light>`'s `light` actually means?

After I change

```
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
    theme: {
        primary: colors.purple,
        secondary: colors.grey.darken1,
        accent: colors.shades.black,
        error: colors.red.accent3
    }
})
```

Nothing happens to `<v-toolbar>` and I have to apply `color` attribute to every element, e.g. `<v-btn color="primary">primary</v-btn>`.

After I specific a color, keyword `dark` will only affect font color. 
e.g. `<v-toolbar color="primary" dark>` will show primary color and white font.

That is not what I want, how to replace default `dark`and `light` with totally custom theme colors. [example theme](https://material.io/tools/color/#!/?view.left=0&view.right=0&primary.color=FFA726&secondary.color=E0E0E0&primary.text.color=FAFAFA)

Comment: It's weird, for me it works. Can you `console.log(colors)`?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik, I have replaced `colors` with hex and still not work, please look at this code pen: https://codepen.io/paleneutron/pen/YdVeGR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit the dark and light theme css by going into the vuetify code and editing their style files. They use stylus and any edits should be reflected immediately. To find the style code go to:

`yourproject/node_modules/vuetify/src/stylus/settings/_theme.styl`

and in there you'll find

```
$material-light := {
...
}
```

and

```
$material-dark := {
...
}
```

which have the styling for background, fonts, cards, etc.

You should be able to edit it as you see fit.

**Otherwise** to save editing your node modules folder you can do the following:

1. create a folder called stylus in your src folder
2. create a file called main.styl
3. add this to that file: `@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/main'`
4. Then in your main.js add this `import './stylus/main.styl`
5. If you then restart your app the styles should now be working from your import.
6. Edit your src/main.styl file **before** the import statement and any changes will override the default

eg:

```
//src/stylus/main.styl
$material-light.background = #36EF45
$body-font-family = 'Raleway'
$alert-font-size = 18px

@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/main'
```

Anything you don't change will stay with the default.

Comment: Is there any way to overwrite it in my code instead of edit npm library?

Comment: @PaleNeutron, I've edited. Is a more responsible solution.

Comment: This no longer works, since Vuetify is no longer using Stylus.